# Sonar local analysis exclusion patterns

Tags: eclipse, code-analysis, sonarqube

I've got a configured Sonar server and a lot of clients using it via the Eclipse Sonar 2.4 plugin. I configured the excluded resources using the server's "Exclusion filers" menu (under the Configuration). The server skips the related resources indeed, however when running the local analysis, the patterns do not seem to work. E.g. I don't want the plugin Activators to be checked; on the server they aren't, but the local analysis check them.

Is there any solution for "synching" the exclusion patterns with (from) the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is available with Sonar Eclipse 3.0.

You can see the prerequisites [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/SonarQube+in+Eclipse)